# Scala DAG update several parents

Tags: scala, data-structures, immutability

I already know that immutable data-structures cannot have cycles in Scala.

However how do you handle child updates with multiple parents?

```
val child = Child("Tom")
val mother = Parent("Susi", child)
val father = Parent("Chuck", child)
val renamedChild = child.copy(name = "Tommy")
// how to update both references?
```

I haven't looked that much into Zippers but I think they would only work for simple trees not DAG's right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In immutable / persistent data structures, you have structural sharing, so when you perform an update, part of the overall structure must be updated. For a hierarchical structure like a tree (as your example suggests), this means you must update, top-to-bottom, the path from root to your child. This in turn requires that you have knowledge about your parents.

If `mother` and `father` were "freely floating" around without a root, you would have to update them as well:

```
val mother1 = mother.copy(child = renamedChild)
val father1 = father.copy(child = renamedChild)
```

If you have nested data structures and you want to avoid doing the book-keeping manually (which can easily result in mistakes), you can use an approach such as [Lenses](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1zW1Gm2M_x_cn9pGp6LQDwHDXQ4WSa4JTBQe1ADBtKjw/).

If your structure is a directed-acyclic-graph, finding an immutable implementation can be a challenge (I'm not aware of a persistent DAG structure—it's probably doable, decomposing the DAG into a set of trees, but I have not come across any such implementation).

---

Of course you can always have a naive (not well performing) version.

```
// set of vertices and map that points from children to parents!
type Graph[A] = (Set[A], Map[A, Set[A]])

def update[A](graph: Graph[A], before: A, now: A): Graph[A] = {
  val (vertices, edges) = graph
  val newV    = vertices - before + now
  val parents = edges.getOrElse(before, Set.empty)
  val newE    = if (parents.isEmpty) edges else edges - before + (now -> parents)
  (newV, newE)
}

val g1 = Set("Tom", "Susi", "Chuck") -> Map("Tom" -> Set("Susi", "Chuck"))
val g2 = update(g1, "Tom", "Tommy")
```